# Getting the ajaxsearch link on the web page

Tags: webserver

On this site, mnemonicdictionary.com, on the centre part of the page, they show the meanings of the word queried in the search text box. I want to write a script which will fetch just the central part of this page ( as in just the meanings part) for a list of words. But I am not able to get the search url for that part of the page. Could someone could provide me that url so it would be like www.mnemonicdictionary.com/XXXX%s for that central part of the page where %s can be replaced by the word. I want to append them for all words to a single html file for offline viewing.

I know of this: http://mnemonicdictionary.com/?word=hello
But it still fetches the entire page. I just want the central part.

Earlier some days back, this used to work for me: 
www.mnemonicdictionary.com/include/ajaxSearch.php?word=%s

but this does not work any more. I dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got the url. I was just looking at the source. It is

www.mnemonicdictionary.com/includes/ajaxSearch.php?word=%s